# How to find a value of array inside another array then set data accordingly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

I have this first array:

```
const arrayOne = [
    {number: "DS5.11", name: "nameOne"},
    {number: "DS5.11", name: "nameTwo"},
    {number: "D5.10", name: "NameThree"}
]
```

Then I have this second array. Similar to the first one:

```
const arrayOne = [
    {number: "DS5.11", name: "nameFour"},
    {number: "DS5.85", name: "nameFive"},
    {number: "D5SA1", name: "NameSix"}
]
```

As you can see, the first and second number values of the first array are equal to the same first number value of the second array. So what I've been trying to do is to filter the first array, check the number, and basically, if there's a number from the first array that it's repeated on the second array, a new object is created.

Something like:

```
let arrayThree = []
arrayOne.filter((e,i) => {
    arrayTwo.map((obj,idx) => { if(obj.number === e.number) {
        arrayThree[i] = {key: value}
    }})
})
```

Also, I want this new object to have as many index numbers as there are matches between the first and the second array.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please specify how the final `arraythrree` should look like. Please add the expected output in the question.

Comment: `map` and `filter` return new arrays. Are you wanting to include in the output the union/intersection of the two arrays? Please include a sample expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but here's my solution:

```
arrayOne.filter(obj1 => {

    
    for (obj2 of arrayTwo) {
        if (obj1.number === obj2.number) {
            arrayThree.push({ key: obj1.number });
            return false; 
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
});
```

This method filters ArrayOne values, and save the repeated numbers inside arrayThree.
ArrayTwo keeps untouched.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. The one with lodash did too, but I'd rather do it without an external library. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use lodash the following code should work

```
  const arrayOne = [
        {number: "DS5.11", name: "nameOne"},
        {number: "DS5.11", name: "nameTwo"},
        {number: "D5.10", name: "NameThree"}
    ]

    const arrayTwo = [
        {number: "DS5.11", name: "nameFour"},
        {number: "DS5.85", name: "nameFive"},
        {number: "D5SA1", name: "NameSix"}
    ]

    console.log(_.intersectionBy(arrayOne,arrayTwo,"number"))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save the `name` property of arrayOne then

```
let arrayThree = [];
arrayOne.filter((e,i) => {
    arrayTwo.map((obj,idx) => { if(obj.number === e.number) {
        arrayThree[i] = e;
    }})
})
```

similarly to save the `name` property of arrayTwo

```
let arrayThree = [];
arrayOne.filter((e,i) => {
    arrayTwo.map((obj,idx) => { if(obj.number === e.number) {
        arrayThree[i] = obj;
    }})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a map of number to array of elements using array 1

```
const intersectionMap = arrayOne.reduce(
  (obj, el) => {
    if (!obj[el.number]) obj[el.number] = [];
    obj[el.number].push(el)
    return obj;
  },
  {}
);
```

Iterate over array 2 and if intersection map has key, push element into array

```
arrayTwo.forEach(el => obj[el.number]?.push(el));
```

Filter out arrays with length 1 and flatten result arrays

```
const res = Object.values(obj).flatMap(arr => arr.length > 1 ? arr : []);
```

No nested loops so `O(n)` runtime complexity.

```js
const arrayOne = [
  { number: "DS5.11", name: "nameOne" },
  { number: "DS5.11", name: "nameTwo" },
  { number: "D5.10", name: "NameThree" }
];

const arrayTwo = [
  { number: "DS5.11", name: "nameFour" },
  { number: "DS5.85", name: "nameFive" },
  { number: "D5SA1", name: "NameSix" }
];

const intersectionMap = arrayOne.reduce(
  (obj, el) => {
    if (!obj[el.number]) obj[el.number] = [];
    obj[el.number].push(el)
    return obj;
  },
  {}
);

arrayTwo.forEach(el => intersectionMap[el.number]?.push(el));

const res = Object.values(intersectionMap).flatMap(arr => arr.length > 1 ? arr : []);

console.log(res);
```